# ERROR: Failed to create helper child read FD: UDP[::1]

Tags: squid

everyone,

I'm new to squid, and I can't start my squid. Here is my problem, when typing: `sudo squid -N -d1` to start squid

```

```
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Starting Squid Cache version 3.5.12 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu... 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Service Name: squid 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Process ID 8714 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Process Roles: master worker 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| With 65535 file descriptors available 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Initializing IP Cache... 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 8 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 9 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Adding nameserver 100.100.2.138 from /etc/resolv.conf 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Adding nameserver 100.100.2.136 from /etc/resolv.conf 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Unlinkd pipe opened on FD 15 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Local cache digest enabled; rebuild/rewrite every 3600/3600 sec 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Store logging disabled 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Swap maxSize 102400 + 262144 KB, estimated 28041 objects 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Target number of buckets: 1402 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Using 8192 Store buckets 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Max Swap size: 102400 KB 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Rebuilding storage in /var/spool/squid (clean log) 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Using Least Load store dir selection 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Finished loading MIME types and icons. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| HTCP Disabled. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 19 to [::1]: (99) Cannot assign requested address 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 20 to [::1]: (99) Cannot assign requested address 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| ERROR: Failed to create helper child read FD: UDP[::1] 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| /var/run/squid/squid.pid: (2) No such file or directory 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| WARNING: Could not write pid file 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Adaptation support is off. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Accepting HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:3128 remote=[::] FD 18 flags=9 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Done reading /var/spool/squid swaplog (0 entries) 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Store rebuilding is 0.00% complete 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Finished rebuilding storage from disk. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 Entries scanned 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 Invalid entries. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 With invalid flags. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 Objects loaded. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 Objects expired. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 Objects cancelled. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 Duplicate URLs purged. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|         0 Swapfile clashes avoided. 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|   Took 0.03 seconds (  0.00 objects/sec). 
2018/04/17 20:32:25| Beginning Validation Procedure 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|   Completed Validation Procedure 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|   Validated 0 Entries 
2018/04/17 20:32:25|   store_swap_size = 0.00 KB 
2018/04/17 20:32:26| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
```

```

My system is ubuntu16.04. My Squid version is 3.5.12 and is installed using apt-get.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Duplicates https://serverfault.com/questions/882152/cannot-bind-socket-error-for-squid-proxy .  Probably you are running in a Docker container or some other environment where IPv6 is not available by-default.  You can ignore this if you aren't using IPv6 with Squid.